# How To Change Color of "Texts" in VSCode

Tags: colors, themes, visual-studio-code

**As you can see, the texts underlined with red are gray. I want to change their color. No matter what I tried in settings.json, I didn't manage to change it. How can I do it ?**

[image: IMG 1]

[image: IMG 2]

[image]

Comment: if this text does not have a particular Textmate Class you have to change the default text color

Comment: @rioV8 how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Rago, by color code means you want to change the color code for text you wrote?

You can change the theme from settings or  Ctrl+K / Ctrl+T

Comment: I want to change that without changing the current color theme that I'm using. So, I want to override theme settings. 

`code`
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#fff",

    "numbers": "#FF0000"
  },
`code`

Just like this